# Trazer informações do usuário no model

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, where

Tenho um código que lista vários relatórios. Esses relatórios estão salvos no banco de dados e para chama-los eu uso o **Model** no **CodeIgniter**. Dentro do model, tenho um `where` e para fazer funcionar perfeitamente, com as informações que eu quero, preciso pegar um dado do usuário que está visualizando essa lista.

**Exemplo**: Conseguir pegar o estado que o usuário está cadastrado, para colocar dentro do `where`.

Por enquanto está assim meu model:

```
$this->datatables->select('relatorios.l_id, relatorios.l_tipo_inspecao, empr.e_nome, relatorios.l_data_hora, user.u_nome, relatorios.l_status');
        $this->datatables->from('relatorios');
        $this->datatables->join('user', 'relatorios.u_id = user.u_id');
        $this->datatables->join('dispo', 'relatorios.d_id = dispo.d_id');
        $this->datatables->join('empr', 'empr.e_id = user.e_id');
        $this->datatables->where('user.u_uf', 'SC');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
```

Nesse `where('user.u_uf', 'SC');` o ***SC*** que precisa ser a dado pego do usuário.

Comment: Se você referenciar uma variável no lugar do `'SC'` não resolve? algo como `$_POST["uf_usuario"]` ?

Comment: @MarllonNasser eu tentei colocar uma variável, mas não tive sucesso ao tentar passar o  estado pra ela

Comment: Posta o código do seu formulário com a action... edita na sua pergunta :)

Comment: esse usuario seria o usuario logado?